# Javascript (K - Nearest Neighbour)

Tags: javascript, knn

I'm trying to implement a basic KNN algorithm in Javascript.

Firstly I need to get the square distance of the Mystery Vector to all of the other vectors.

I want to be able to retrieve the name of the 'array' the vectors are from once this is done.

For example after I have found the 3 closest neighbouring vectors, how do I log what array these vectors have come from,something like;the three closest vectors are '3,4' (BANANA) . '3,5'(BANANA), '3,1'(Strawberry)

```
//colours on y axis 
// 1 = blue
// 2 = green
// 3 = Red
// 4 = Yellow

//Size on x axis (cm)


function storeCoordinate(x, y, array) {
    array.push(x);
    array.push(y);
}

var Apples = [];
storeCoordinate(3, 5, Apples); // a - Apple
storeCoordinate(3, 6, Apples); // b - Apple
storeCoordinate(3, 7, Apples); // c - Apple
storeCoordinate(3, 4, Apples); // d - Apple

var Bananas = [];
storeCoordinate(4, 8, Bananas); // e - Banana
storeCoordinate(4, 9, Bananas); // f - Banana
storeCoordinate(4, 10, Bananas); //g - Banana
storeCoordinate(4, 7, Bananas); // h - Banana

var Strawberries = [];
storeCoordinate(3, 3, Strawberries); // i - Strawberry
storeCoordinate(3, 2, Strawberries); //j  - Strawberry
storeCoordinate(3, 1, Strawberries); // k - Strawberry
storeCoordinate(3, 4, Strawberries); //l  - Strawberry

var X = 3 ;
var Y = 5;
// mystery vector

var a = ( (Apples[0]-X)*(Apples[0]-X) + (Apples[1]-Y)*(Apples[1]-Y) );
var b = ( (Apples[2]-X)*(Apples[2]-X) + (Apples[3]-Y)*(Apples[3]-Y) );
var c = ( (Apples[4]-X)*(Apples[4]-X) + (Apples[5]-Y)*(Apples[5]-Y) );
var d = ( (Apples[6]-X)*(Apples[6]-X) + (Apples[7]-Y)*(Apples[7]-Y) );

console.log(c);
```

Comment: Maybe clarify what you are asking. The title suggests a question about kNN, but the actual question seems to be about logging the result. If you want to attract answers, the question should match the title. Also, what have you tried in terms of logging? What went wrong? Could you provide a minimal example?